# MS sql database connetion error

Tags: sql-server

I received this error when trying connecting to a MS SQL Instance.

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.

Can anyone suggest how to fix this error?

Comment: Much, much more information is required. Generally: are you sure you can actually reach the server you're trying to connect to? Try to ping it to see.

Comment: Does the instance have a name other than the Default? If so, are you supplying the name? If it's not on the default port, is named ports set up, is the Browser Service running, or are you specifying the port? Like @MK_ said, we need a lot more information here.

Answer (score 0):

This error mostly occurs when the server name provided is wrong.

- Check the server name and make sure it is correct

Try to connect to the server by pinging from `cmd`

`ping servername`